# SQL Update based on aggregate record set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with purchase orders:

```
po_line table
+--------+---------+-----------+
| po_num | po_line | date      |
+--------+---------+-----------+
| 1      | 1       | 9/22/2013 |
| 1      | 2       | 9/22/2013 |
| 1      | 3       | 9/22/2013 |
| 2      | 1       | 9/21/2013 |
| 2      | 2       | NULL      |
+--------+---------+-----------+

po table
+--------+-----------+
| po_num | confirmed |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | NULL      |
| 2      | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+
```

For a given po, example po_num 1, I am wanting to update a value in table 2 to 'confirmed' if all the records have a date in them for those lines.  Example 1 would populate confirmed.  PO 2 would fail the criteria since line 2 has no date.

Do I need to use a cursor to do this? Running sql 2008 r2.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to reformat your example dataset to render properly - it will help quite a bit with getting an answer. Edit: Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE po SET confirmed = 'confirmed'
FROM po T
WHERE 
NOT T.po_num   IN 
(
SELECT po_num FROM po_line
WHERE po_date IS NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want to make sure that are entries for each `po` in the `po_line` table before confirming, you can use:

```
update po set confirmed = 'confirmed'
  where po.po_num in (select po_num from
    (select po_num, count(po_date) dated, count(*) total from po_line group by po_num) q
       where dated=total)
```

as shown in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b16988/8/0

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion.  I will remember to check for things like this going forward. These should always have values since the po record is created first and is a parent of the po_lines. I like that comparing the totals of the two though.  Thats great.  I was looking at doing some averages, but this works well. The only this is that " Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." but I don't think this should be an issue in this case, was just a warning.